# How to responsive fixed or sticky last column in datatable with bootstrap4?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have collapse navbar but when i hide the navbar the sticky column duplicated or overlapping two last column. Please refer screenshot. Answer is appreciated thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMOAF.png)

```
defaultSetting: {
    autoWidth: false,
    fixedHeader: true,
    searchDelay: 500,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: false,
    scrollResize: true,
    responsive: true,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 1,
      rightColumns: 1,
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share you code.

Comment: defaultSetting: {
        autoWidth: false,
        fixedHeader: true,
        searchDelay: 500,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: false,
        scrollResize: true,
        responsive: true,
        fixedColumns: {
          leftColumns: 1,
          rightColumns: 1,
        }